# Using jquery animate properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not a total wizard at jQuery, so I just need some clarification: shouldn't the code below be free of any errors? If you look at the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Awesomennjawarrior/pen/YQMPab), you'll see that it throws an 'unexpected identifier' at line 9.

```
$('.tester').animate({
      opacity: 1,
        },
        {
              duration: 500,
            progress: function(a, p, c ) {
            //whatever
            }
            complete: function() {
          //whatever
        }
        });
```

Comment: do not use JQUERY for animation, use CSS3,

Comment: Missing comma after progress method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma before complete: function().